# What is the best way to `yield` over a collection/list that only exists inside of a callback, in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have a method (`_all`) that has a callback (`_runInTxn`) inside. The callback gets the list (`rs`) that I would like to `yield` over and return via _all's Stream. However, the callback isn't marked with `async*` (but the method is marked as `async*`).

What is the best way to `yield` over a collection/list that only exists inside of a callback?

Here is an example of what is correct and works:

```dart
  Stream<String> _all() async* {
    var sql = 'SELECT id,value FROM $storeName';
    SqlResultSet resultSet;

    await _runInTxn((txn) {
      txn.executeSql(sql, [], (txn, rs) {
        resultSet = rs;
      });
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; ++i) {
      var row = resultSet.rows.item(i);
      yield row['value'];
    }
  }
```

I'm curious if there's a better way to write this code, so I can avoid a null `resultSet`. I'd really love to have my `yield` statement inside of the `executeSql` statement. Can I do a "non-local yield" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar discussion about using `yield` inside `Future.forEach()` and the answer was as far as I remember that this is not supported (couldn't find the discussion yet).

I guess it would be easier without async*

```dart
Stream<String> _all() {
  var sql = 'SELECT id,value FROM $storeName';
  var sc = new StreamController<String>();

  _runInTxn((txn) {
    txn.executeSql(sql, [], (txn, rs) {
      rs.rows.forEach((row) => sc.add(row['value']));
    });
  }).then((_) => sc.close());

  return sc.stream;
}
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f6eab34d40c0ee4e4652)

Comment: Found the discussion: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/vm-dev/3Z-SWliwmEU/Zri-evFoDkgJ

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using StreamController.